# How can I get the current local hostname using C# or VB.NET?

Tags: c#, vb.net, winforms

I need to get the host name currently running the application. Any idea?

Comment: Why have you yags vb.net when the title says c#.

Comment: C# or VB.NET ... Any would be accepted

Answer (score 107, accepted):

Something to bear in mind is that `System.Environment.MachineName;` and `System.Windows.Forms.SystemInformation.ComputerName;` will give you the NETBIOS name of the machine (restricted to 15 characters).

If you want the full TCP/IP based host name you can  use [`Dns.GetHostName()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.dns.gethostname.aspx):

```
string hostName = System.Net.Dns.GetHostName();
```

Or you can use:

```
System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("COMPUTERNAME");
```

Which will return the full computer name set during installation.

Comment: Well, the docs are a bit vague on how it's implemented, but it is implied that it requires a)  a working network connection, b) a round-trip to the DNS server, and c) that the DNS actually knows your machine name (it doesn't have to, unless your a server)

Comment: @James Curran - Absolutely. But Environment.MachineName restricts the computer name to a 15 character NETBIOS name. GetHostName will retrieve the full TCP/IP based hostname.

Comment: `System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("COMPUTERNAME");` is Windows only

Comment: Will this still work if the code is running on IIS? What will it return? something like "www.mySiteAddress.com" ??

Answer (score 36):

Unless I am mistaken on what you want to do..

```
System.Environment.MachineName
```

Answer (score 11):

To get fully qualified name, use:

```
 System.Net.Dns.GetHostEntry("").HostName
```

Answer (score 4):

The My namespace contains many great "helper" functions like:

```
My.Computer.Name
```

Comment: This appears to be limited to VB.NET and is proprietary to that language:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/ms789188.aspx

Comment: So sweet, thank you. VB is so cute.

Answer (score 2):

```
System.Windows.Forms.SystemInformation.ComputerName;
```

Comment: Looks like this one also gets the NetBIOS name, so the same as `System.Environment.MachineName` and avoiding a potentially awkward System.Windows.Forms situation.